# Finding files by type and renaming them based on their parent directory

Tags: shell, unix, find, mv

So I've rigorously looked through the internet as best I can to attempt to find something to help me remedy the problem I'm currently experiencing.

For example I have a file with many directories and within these both documents and images are contained.

My goal is rename these files to being based on their parent folder, for example:

/main/secondary/file

as all my files are already generically named, I wish to be able to rename my images to secondary0001.jpg secondary0002.jpg and so on.

I've been looking all over and attempting to use all manner of methods to create a working script.

Currently I feel this may be my best effort so far.

```
find $2 -type f -iname IMG_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].jpg -exec mv -n {}$dirname {}.jpg\;
```

$2 contains the folder of my overall folder, so $2 would equate to Alpha/Primary/Secondary/file

I'd really appreciate any kind of assistance, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Your question isn't all that clear yet.  You mention `/main/secondary/file` but seem to want to rename `IMG_0001.jpg` to `secondary0001.jpg` in the `secondary` folder, so the `/main/secondary` part is an example of a directory, but the `file` part would be mapped to an image JPEG file.  And then you've got `Alpha/Primary/Secondary/file`, and it isn't clear what you're doing with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your image file names don't contain white space and your folder names don't contain white space (so there's no need for extreme antics to deal with extremely awkward file names), then you can consider:

```
find "$directory" -type f -iname 'IMG_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].jpg' -print |
while read file
do
    base=$(basename "$file")
    dir=$(dirname "$file")
    bdir=$(basename "$dir")
    suffix=$(echo "$base" | sed 's/^[Ii][Mm][Gg]_//')
    mv "$file" "$dir/$bdir$suffix"
done
```

I didn't say anything about efficient.  Since you didn't tag this with Bash or Ksh, I didn't assume any of their facilities for variable editing.  Apart from the use of `$(…)` in lieu of back-ticks `` `…` `` and the `-iname` option to `find`, this would work with essentially any shell derived from the Bourne shell in the last 20 years or so.

If you decide you need spaces etc in your directory or file names, you will need to review the code.  It is likely mostly safe (because it uses double quotes around variable references like `"$file"`), but you need to really worry if your file names or directory names can contain newlines.

---

> Using your method I've now got around to a method of renaming these files. However, when I rename them based on their directory, I'm writing over each file and losing many. Is there a way to avoid this such as adding digits to the end of the filename?

1. Test by putting an `echo` in front of the `mv` so you know what will happen, without actually making it happen.
2. I think you must have either modified the code or have a slightly different situation from what was reasonably inferred.  There's an example below with a set of empty files in a brand new junk directory hierarchy.  The input names are unique per directory; the output names are unique per directory; there's no way for the script to generate collisions and lose data unless there are already files using the revised naming scheme present in the directory.  Even if you move the files up a level, the names should all be unique because the subdirectories were unique in the first place.

Example run:

```
$ mkdir junk
$ cd junk
$ for dir in primary secondary tertiary
> do (mkdir $dir; cd $dir; touch $(seq -f 'IMG_%04.0f.jpg' 1 10))
> done
$ ls
primary   secondary tertiary
$ ls *
primary:
IMG_0001.jpg IMG_0002.jpg IMG_0003.jpg IMG_0004.jpg IMG_0005.jpg IMG_0006.jpg IMG_0007.jpg IMG_0008.jpg IMG_0009.jpg IMG_0010.jpg

secondary:
IMG_0001.jpg IMG_0002.jpg IMG_0003.jpg IMG_0004.jpg IMG_0005.jpg IMG_0006.jpg IMG_0007.jpg IMG_0008.jpg IMG_0009.jpg IMG_0010.jpg

tertiary:
IMG_0001.jpg IMG_0002.jpg IMG_0003.jpg IMG_0004.jpg IMG_0005.jpg IMG_0006.jpg IMG_0007.jpg IMG_0008.jpg IMG_0009.jpg IMG_0010.jpg
$ directory=.
$ find "$directory" -type f -iname 'IMG_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].jpg' -print |
> while read file
> do
>     base=$(basename "$file")
>     dir=$(dirname "$file")
>     bdir=$(basename "$dir")
>     suffix=$(echo "$base" | sed 's/^[Ii][Mm][Gg]_//')
>     mv "$file" "$dir/$bdir$suffix"
> done
$ ls
primary   secondary tertiary
$ ls *
primary:
primary0001.jpg primary0003.jpg primary0005.jpg primary0007.jpg primary0009.jpg
primary0002.jpg primary0004.jpg primary0006.jpg primary0008.jpg primary0010.jpg

secondary:
secondary0001.jpg secondary0003.jpg secondary0005.jpg secondary0007.jpg secondary0009.jpg
secondary0002.jpg secondary0004.jpg secondary0006.jpg secondary0008.jpg secondary0010.jpg

tertiary:
tertiary0001.jpg tertiary0003.jpg tertiary0005.jpg tertiary0007.jpg tertiary0009.jpg
tertiary0002.jpg tertiary0004.jpg tertiary0006.jpg tertiary0008.jpg tertiary0010.jpg
$
```

When I created 1000 files in each directory and timed the move, it took 46 seconds to rename the 3000 files (running on Mac OS X 10.10.4 with a hard disk and no SSD).  That's a bit longer than I expected.

Revising the script  as shown below changes the runtime on 1000 files per directory down to 8 seconds (from 46), a speed up of about 5.  That's a worthwhile improvement, but it still feels like the script is not running as fast as a modern Linux might — but that could be a combination of ancient machine, hard disks, HTFS file system, and Mac OS X overhead (the title bar of the window changes the currently running command name as the script is running, for example).

```
directory='.'
time find "$directory" -type f -iname 'IMG_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].jpg' -print |
while read file
do
    #base=$(basename "$file")
    base=${file##*/}
    #dir=$(dirname "$file")
    dir=${file%/*}
    #bdir=$(basename "$dir")
    bdir=${dir#*/}
    #suffix=$(echo "$base" | sed 's/^[Ii][Mm][Gg]_//')
    suffix=${base/[Ii][Mm][Gg]_/}
    mv "$file" "$dir/$bdir$suffix"
done
```

To get much further improvement, I'd go to Perl and have it do the rename operation as a system call instead of invoking a separate program.  This would cut down a lot more process overhead (there are still 3000 `mv` commands in the revised script, whereas Perl or an equivalent would have just one process for the whole move).

Note that the parameter substitutions work because the names are constrained to be well-behaved (there is at least one slash in each of them; the root directory isn't named, etc).  Edge cases dealt with by `basename` and `dirname` commands are not handled by the parameter substitutions. Be cautious about generalizing.

Comment: Sorry if my original question wasn't so clear, this is on bash. This looks rather smooth and understandable for me, I won't have any spaces on directories or filenames. Assuming that I'm dealing with a say 1000 images,  would this considered fast or slow?

Comment: I'd expect it to take no more than a couple of seconds for a thousand files, but I've not gone and tried it.  If this is going to be a one-off operation, speed isn't a major issue, anyway.  If you're going to be doing it often (say several times an hour), then maybe you'd worry about its performance.  If you're using Bash, you could replace the calls to `basename` and `dirname` and `sed` with parameter expansion notations (`${…}`).  But it isn't urgent that you do so.

Comment: So using your method I've now got around to a method of renaming these files, however when I rename them based on their directory I'm writing over each file and losing many, is there a way to avoid this such as adding digits to the end of the filename. Thanks so much for your help thus far, it's been invaluable.

Comment: Ok, thanks for further explaining this and I greatly appreciate that you've found an even quicker method, 8 seconds is not bad at all, on top of this. All files have generic numbers on them, however I was wondering if it's possible to apply a new number per each file.

For example:

Img_0372.jpg to become secondary1.jpg
Img_2248.jpg to become secondary2.jpg

It's worth mentioning if it's also possible to limit the amount of characters to be copied from the dirname such as substrings,

Ex: Second1.jpg

If I've made that understandable enough, again..many thanks for your continued support.

Comment: If you can devise a reliable implementable scheme, it can be done.  You're in charge of the editing — you choose what the name is mapped to.  The onus is on you to ensure that the new name is unique, of course.  What algorithm do you want to use to map 0372 to 2248? There are many options; what do you want to map 0371 and 0373 to? Substringing of names comes in the "you're in charge" category; you decide how to modify the loop body to edit `secondary` to `second`.  It depends how general purpose you need the code to be. I'd probably retrench to Perl (but I've been using it for over 20 years).

Comment: I'm really just trying to stick to the principles of the shell script itself and not go into perl as it's unfamiliar territory to myself, I think with the scheme you've provided I can come to a conclusion of how to ideally set format up, I'm gonna recode my script and hopefully that it will be at it's conclusion after this.

How you advise creating a truncated section of the dirname?

I'm assuming a good option would be truncdirname=$(dirname:1:8 "$file") or there abouts?

Comment: Look up Bash [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).  Given `dir=…some-value…`, you can get the first 8 characters with `truncdirname=${dir:0:8}` (offset 0, length 8).  It works sanely when the input is shorter than 8.  Be wary of negative offsets; they work, but require a space between the colon and the number (`${dir: -8:8}` for the last 8 characters, though the length is not needed for that; `${dir: -8:5}` would be more interesting).

Comment: Oh, and you need arithmetic for the sequencing.  You can mess with [shell arithmetic](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic) and [arithmetic expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion).  The main issue is keeping track of which was the last number you used, and what do you do if the file you plan to create already exists?  For example, if you planned to create `second1.jpg` but it is already there; do you keep trying 2, 3, 4, etc until you reach the first gap or the end (with 1000 files)?  How do you track what's there?  Etc.

Comment: The file won't pre-exist, second1.jpg won't exist at least until an operation creates it, so it would only go forward from there.